# Array is printed as 0's in Intel 32-bit assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I made a program and initialized an array like `var WORD 50 DUP(?)`.
When I tried a loop and printed the value of *var*, it printed zeroes.

```
.data
var WORD 50 DUP(?)
.code
main PROC
mov ecx,10
top:
movzx eax,var
call writeint
loop top
```

Comment: Presumably `writeint` expects the value of first integer in `eax`.  You repeatedly load and write the same value ten times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@vitsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011614/array-is-printed-0-in-assembly-intel-32-bit#comment130682714_74011614) said, the value of *var* is printed each time, as nothing changes between iterations.

What you want to do is **load the address** of *var* to **EBX**, *dereference and increment it by 2 at each iteration*.

```
.data
    var WORD 50 DUP(?)
.code
    main PROC
        lea   ebx, var
        mov   ecx,10
    top:
        movzx eax, WORD PTR [ebx]
        add   ebx, 2
        call  writeint
        dec   ecx
        jnz   top
```